# Printing a list of email subject lines and recipients

Tags: email, printing

I need to print the subject lines, recipients and timestamps of several hundred emails in list form.

Although taking screengrabs of my email client and pasting them into one image would work, I'd prefer to find a less dirty way. Are there any clients that allow you to do this? Or any scripts I could run over the raw emails themselves?

Comment: 1) How do you access your mails? (POP/IMAP) 2) Which operating system? 3) Which client are you using now?

Comment: I can access them pretty much any way I like, including pulling them straight off the server as a big xml file. OSX or Win7. The person whose emails they are uses RoundCube webmail to access them, which doesn't play well with printing or copy pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formail and procmail will help you here, procmail can parse a set of messages and hand them to formail to extract the information you want.

How you get the messages to those programs is a different question, and will depend on how they're stored. If they're stored in mbox format then I *think* procmail can read them directly, but I'm not sure how flexible it is with that.

Comment: Of course, if the questioner is about to add the [`exchange-2010`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exchange-2010) tag to the question in response to slhck's comment, this answer isn't going to be worth much. ☺

Comment: Formail looks like exactly what I need, thanks for the help (I'm a new member so I can't vote up)

Comment: If they're on the server then you can use getmail to pass them to procmail. I believe both are available for OSX.